# How do I remove the printable area marks in Word 2003?

Tags: microsoft-word-2003

Suddenly, and without warning, Word 2003 has started displaying (what I think is) markers to indicate the printable area on a page.

They can only be seen when you are in the "Print Layout" view and are circled in red in the picture below:

[image]

Try as I might, I cannot find anything in "Preferences" or "Page Setup" that turns this off.

Does anyone know how to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are called *crop marks*. Don't know if you have seen [this article from Microsoft](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/839371) regarding this problem in Word 2003. It suggests disabling Asian languages that are installed.

1. On the Start Menu under Microsoft Office Tools, find the **Microsoft Office 2003 Language Settings** program and run it.
2. In the **Enabled languages** list, select and remove these languages, assuming you're not using them:

   - Chinese (Traditional)
   - Chinese (Simplified)
   - Japanese
   - Korean

---

In later versions of Word these lines can be enabled/disabled by looking for the **Crop Marks** checkbox in the **Advanced** section of the main **Options** window.

Comment: That did the trick. For some unknown reason I had Japanese installed. As soon as I removed it, the crop marks disappeared.

Comment: Glad I could help. It seems like a bug that Microsoft have fixed in more recent versions as you can now enable and disable them in the Options window.